# If you pass a lambda function by copy what actually gets copied?

Tags: c++

If you pass a lambda function by copy in c++ what actually gets copied?

Is it just a pointer to the lambda?

Or does the whole capture list get copied as well?

Comment: lambdas are essentially just syntax sugar for creating anonymous structs with an overloaded `operator()` - so think about how passing a struct by value behaves

Answer (score 5):

Lambda functions are usually realized as compiler generated [functor classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/what-are-c-functors-and-their-uses).

> Or does the whole capture list get copied as well?

The captures go to the class internal data members, and those will be copied.